# CIFilter has changed UIImage Aspect Ratio - SWIFT

Tags: ios, colors, uiimage, cifilter

I have implemented a CIFilter to profileImages in my iOS app. I have added orientation to prevent pixelation but I am suffering from the **aspect ratio** "ScaleAspectFill" not being applied to the images. The same images in colour have the perfect aspect ratio...i.e. when I just have:

```
self.p1ProfilePic.image = p1Img
```

1. I have specified exact height and widths for the profile images in Storyboard.
2. I have tried adding programmatically the .contentMode as .ScaleAspectFill but with no effect whatsoever.
3. What am I missing here? CGRect?

   ```
           let originalImageP1 = CIImage(image: p1Img!)
           let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectTonal")
           filter!.setDefaults()
           filter!.setValue(originalImageP1, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
           let outputImage = filter!.outputImage
           self.p1ProfilePic.image = UIImage(CIImage: outputImage!, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale, orientation: .Up)
   ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating a `UIImage` from a `CIImage` with your technique creates images that don't respect `contentMode`. Try this instead:

```
let ciContext = CIContext()
let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!,
    fromRect: filter.outputImage!.extent)

self.p1ProfilePic.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
```

Cheers!

Simon

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. Quick question - if I'm using multiple references to a black and white image (like above) within my app... is it just better to run the filter and store the black and white image too? Are CIFilters detrimental to memory & performance?

Comment: If it's the same image, keep it as a CIImage. A CIImage isn't a memory hogging bitmap, it's actually the instructions to create an image and won't be "realised" until it's converted to a renderable format (like UIImage). CIFilters are lightweight too. May I humbly suggest my own book, "Core Image for Swift" :) https://itunes.apple.com/gb/book/core-image-for-swift/id1073029980?mt=13

Comment: I think I'm going to store both images and allow the user to easily switch between the two as they wish. To save having to run this every time or perhaps even multiple times a cell/view is loaded. Thanks for the info, will check it out!

Comment: This is madness! I spent hours (3-4) debugging my scaling logic and Core Image code until i had the idea to render the image using an independent CIContext, resulting in the correct aspect ratio. There is no mention of this in the documentation at all. Really frustrating :/ thanks anyways!