# Converting generated QR Code from CIImage to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avfoundation, qr-code

I have been able to convert a QR code I have generated from a CIImage to UIImage.

However, the resulting UIImage does not have a set aspect ratio.

So, if you put it into a UIImageView with an aspect ratio which isn't 1:1, even if the content mode is set to aspect fit, it stretches the QR code out of proportion.

How can I can convert this QR code to UIImage in such a way that it will hold its aspect ratio if the container view asks for it?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737160/cifilter-has-changed-uiimage-aspect-ratio-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preserve image aspect ratio in iOS UIImageView when doing CIFilter, like CISepiaTone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241773/how-to-preserve-image-aspect-ratio-in-ios-uiimageview-when-doing-cifilter-like)